# How to put a property inside of a react component with onclick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a component from ant.design: https://codesandbox.io/s/kyfov

What I want here is, I want to add "loading" property inside of the component after clicking the component. The loading property will remain for 5 seconds and then will be deleted from the component.

Here, is the coding side of it

Before clicking:

```
<Search 
   placeholder="Customer Id"
   id="CustomerID"
   inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Customer Id" }}
   onChange={onChange}
></Search>
```

After clicking:

```
<Search 
   placeholder="Customer Id"
   id="CustomerID"
   inputProps={{ "aria-label": "Customer Id" }}
   onChange={onChange}
   loading
></Search>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It does not usually do that, you can have the loading prop `loading={loadingState}` and on Click, you can handle the loadingState value true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have made some changes in index.js copy this and add it will work.incase u want to see loader onClicking searchBar use onChange or onClick instead of onSelect

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Input } from "antd";

const { Search } = Input;
const App = () => {
  const [firstLoader, setFirstLoader] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Search
        placeholder="input search loading default"
        onSearch={() => {
          setFirstLoader(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setFirstLoader(false);
          }, 5000);
        }}
        loading={firstLoader}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <Search
        placeholder="input search loading with enterButton"
        loading
        enterButton
      />
    </>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that. You can try maintaining it in the state and then pass it as props to the component. Write an event handler which handles the onClick event of the button(or whatever you are using) and switch the boolean value as per your requirement.